# Retrieving SSIS 2012 environmentvariable.name via power shell

Tags: powershell, ssis

We are using power shell to deploy our 2012 SSIS packages and have environment variables on a SSIS 2012 Server. Now during project deployment I am attempting to loop through eachvariable in the environment variables collection (foreach($variable in $environment.Variables)). That is no problem. I can see "EnvironmentVariable[@Name = 'something']"....however attempting to retrieve the name ("something") from the variable via $variable.Name or $variable.Key doesn't work.  I've tried looping through $environment.Variables.Keys and still nothing. My power shell skills are a little weak since I've been using NANT the past several years but is there something I'm just not seeing?

Thanks in advance,
Anthony

Adding snippet of existing power shell script.  The bolded $variable.Name is not working within the CreateETLPackages task.  There is a lot of setup and other scripts called from this scripts so I haven't included everything.  When $variable.Name is returned in a debug statement it returns "EnvironmentVariable[@Name = 'something']" as I mentoned in my original post:

Task CreateSSISFolder -Depends CreateSSISCatalog {
    if (!$script:SSISCanBeDeployed) { return }

```
# Create the project for the packages in the catalog
$catalog = $script:SSISCatalog
if ($catalog.Folders.Count -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "Creating folder $SSISFolderName ..."
    $script:SSISFolder = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.CatalogFolder" ($catalog, $SSISFolderName, "Folder for EDGE ETL packages")            
    $script:SSISFolder.Create()  
    Write-Host "... done"
} else {
    Write-Host "SSIS folder $SSISFolderName already exists; skipping create"
}
```

}

Task CreateSSISEnvironment -Depends CreateSSISFolder {
    if (!$script:SSISCanBeDeployed) { return }

```
# Create the environment in the project
$folder = $script:SSISFolder
$environment = $folder.Environments[$SSISEnvironmentName]
if ($environment -eq $null) {
    # Create the environment
    Write-Host "Creating environment $SSISEnvironmentName ..."
    $environment = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.EnvironmentInfo" ($folder, $SSISEnvironmentName, "Environment to configure the SSIS packages")
    $environment.Create()
    Write-Host "... done"

    # Now create the variables (Constructor args: variable name, type, default value, sensitivity, description)
    $environment.Variables.Add("TestDatabase", [System.TypeCode]::String, "Data Source=$SSISServerName.TestDatabase;User ID=<USERNAME>;Password=<PASSWORD>;Initial Catalog=EdgeAviTrack;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Persist Security Info=True;Auto Translate=False;", $false, "Connection string for TestDatabase database")
    $environment.Alter()

} else {
    Write-Host "Environment $SSISEnvironmentName already exists; skipping create"
}
```

}

Task CreateETLPackages -Depends CreateSSISFolder, CreateSSISEnvironment {
    if (!$script:SSISCanBeDeployed) { return }

```
# Get list of ETL .ispac files in the solution
$SSISProjects = GetListOfDeploymentFiles "*.ispac"
if ($SSISProjects -ne $null) {
    $folder = $script:SSISFolder
    $environment = $folder.Environments[$SSISEnvironmentName]
    if ($folder -ne $null) {
        foreach ($file in $SSISProjects) {
            # Read the ispac file, and deploy it to the folder            
            [byte[]] $projectFile = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($file.FullName)
            $nameParts = $file.Name.split(".")
            $curProjectName = [string]::join(".", $nameParts[0..($nameParts.length - 2)])
            Write-Debug "Deploying SSIS project $curProjectName"
            $project = $folder.DeployProject($curProjectName, $projectFile)

            if ($project.Status -ne "Success") {
                Write-Error "SSIS packages did not deploy correctly!"
            } else {
                # Get the full information set, rather than the short version returned from DeployProject
                $project = $folder.Projects[$curProjectName]
            }

            # Connect the project to the environment to stitch up all the connection strings
            if ($project.References.Item($SSISEnvironmentName, ".") -eq $null) {
                Write-Host "Adding environment reference to $SSISEnvironmentName ..."
                $project.References.Add($SSISEnvironmentName)
                $project.Alter()
                Write-Host "... done"
            }

            # Connect all the project parameters to the environment variables
            Write-Host "Adding connection string references to environment variables ..."

            foreach($varialble in $environment.Variables) {
                try {
                    $project.Parameters["CM." + **$varialble.Name**  + ".ConnectionString"].Set([Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.ParameterInfo+ParameterValueType]::Referenced, **$variable.Name**)
                }
                catch {
                    Write-Debug "Unable to set connection string **$variable.Name** on SSIS project $curProjectName"
                }
            }
            $project.Alter()
            Write-Host "... done"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This question is about the 2012 SSIS Environment variables/configuration, which is completely unrelated to the operating system's environmental variables. Could you provide more of your powershell script? I started up SQLPS but did not see anything that corresponded to the integration services catalog. I did see Databases\SSISDB but I would have expected something custom.

Comment: billinkc did you happen to get the chance to look over the scripts I sent?  Still trying to figure this one out.  -Thanks Anthony

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found my issue.  Looks like I was trying I need to use the $($object.Name) to get what I need out.  Appreciate those that reached out to for their help.

Thanks,
Anthony